How do I render light separately?
I have the following animation: a surface is illuminated in Cylces by a moving green light. An HDRI is also active.
I thought about this process:

Render: render the animation without the green light
Render: render the green light alone
Composition: multiply/add the green light to render 1

Is there a way to render only the light information of the green light? I was thinking of rendering the render passes (color, direct and indirect) but they also contain the light information of the HDRI. I also thought about turning off the HDRI so that the scene is completely dark, then rendering the scene with the green light and multiplying that render over render 1 (maybe using "screen"). But I don't know if the result is the same as if i rendered everything at once.
The whole example is a simplified version for a current project where I don't want to re-render the whole scene just because I want to change the lights.
